# Required number of permutations for a permutation-based p-value

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, permutation-test, resampling

If I need to calculate a permutation-based $p$-value with significance level $\alpha$, how many permutations do I need ?

From the article ["Permutation Tests for Studying Classifier Performance"](http://jmlr.org/papers/volume11/ojala10a/ojala10a.pdf), page 5 :

> In practice, the upper bound $1/(2\sqrt{k})$ is typically used to determine the number of
> samples required to achieve the desired precision of the test.

... where $k$ is the number of permutations.

How do I calculate the number of required permutations from this formula ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I admit, the paragraph might be confusing.

When performing a permutation test you do estimate a p-value. The issue is, that the estimation of the p-value has an error itself which is calculated as $\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{k}}$. If the error is too large, the p-value is unreliable.

**So how many permutations k does one need to get a reliable estimate ?**

First define your maximum allowed error aka the precision. Let this be $P$. Then an estimated p-value shall be in the interval $[p-3*P,p+3*P]$ (since p is [approximately normal distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_deviation_and_tolerance_intervals))

*Using the upper bound*

The cited paragraph of the paper suggests to use $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{k}}$ as an upper bound estimate of the error instead of $\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{k}}$. This corresponds to a unknown p-value of p=0.5 (where the error is maximum among all ps for a fixed k).

So: You want to know k where $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{k}}\le P$.

<=> $\frac{1}{4P^2}\le k$

But since the cited formula represents an upper bound, this approach is very rough.

*Using the error at the significance level*

Another approach uses the desired significance level $\alpha$ as p to calculate the required precision. This is correct, because the error of the estimated p is more important if we are near the decision threshold (which is the significance level).

In this case one wants to know k where $\sqrt{\frac{\alpha(1-\alpha)}{k}}\le P$.

<=> $\frac{(\alpha(1-\alpha))}{P^2}\le k$

Note that if the true unkown p-value is clearly bigger than $\alpha$, then the error is actually bigger, so p in $[p-3*P,p+3*P]$ does not hold anymore.

*Extending the confidence interval*

This approach corresponds with the center of the confidence interval being right at the decision threshold. In order to force the upper bound of the confidence interval of the estimated p being below the decision threshold (which is more correct), one needs ...

$l\sqrt{\frac{\alpha(1-\alpha)}{k}}\le P$

<=> $(l)^2\frac{(\alpha(1-\alpha))}{P^2}\le k$

where l corresponds to (see again the [graphic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_deviation_and_tolerance_intervals))

```
| l | confidence interval |
| 1 | ~68 % |
| 2 | ~95 % |
| 3 | ~99 % |
```

**Examples:**
Let the desired precison P be 0.005.

Then using the rough upper bound one gets $k>=10000$.

Using P at $\alpha=0.05$ and requesting a 95%-confidence interval one gets $k>=7600$.

For P=0.01 at $\alpha=0.01$ and a 95 % confidence interval one gets k>=396.

*Finally*: I strongly suggest to dive deeper into Monte-Carlo simulations. [The wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_integration) provides a start.

Comment: Thanks, i have reed this:
http://www.epibiostat.ucsf.edu/biostat/sen/statgen/permutation.html#_how_many_permutations_do_we_need 
and I'm trying to compare it to the method written by you. What are the differences in your opinion?

Comment: @Neptune I have updated my answer to create the link. The extended version is now equivalent (aside dropping $(1-\alpha))$, which is an unnecessary simplification IMHO).