# Monte Carlo testing: number of required permutations

Tags: p-value, monte-carlo, permutation-test, resampling

I want to perform a statistical hypothesis test, however I don't know the exact distribution of my test statistic under $H_0$. Therefore, I need to calculate a Monte Carlo estimate $\hat{p}$ of the true p-value.

Problem is, that the test statistic is pretty expensive to compute, so I want to stop permutations as early as possible while still knowing whether I can reject $H_0$ with a certain confidence.

There are several methods out there to limit the number of permutations *in advance* (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80025/required-number-of-permutations-for-a-permutation-based-p-value), e.g.), as well as *sequential* Monte Carlo tests that are supposed to stop even earlier than pre-defined bounds in many cases by iteratively updating the bounds (like the one proposed by [Axel Gandy](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0612488v2)).

On the other hand, if I got it right the CI of $\hat{p}$ can easily be computed using a [binomial proportion confidence interval](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/223664/133568).

**My question:**
Since it would be sufficient to know whether $\hat{p} \leq \alpha$ for a pre-defined confidence level $\alpha$ (rather than having an exact estimate of $p$), would it be possible to just compute the binomial proportion CI after each iteration and stop simulations as soon as $\alpha$ is outside the CI?

My idea would be that this also stops earlier than pre-defined bounds while being less complex than e.g. Gandy's approach.

And if the above is a valid approach, secondary question is what is the difference to approaches like Gandy (i.e. what do I get for the increase in complexity)?